# Show that every curvature of a Frenet curve satisfy the following statement.

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, frenet-frame

I need to show the following statement:

Show that for every Frenet curve $c:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the curvatures $\kappa_1(t),\ldots,\kappa_{n-1}(t)$ satisfy the following equality:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(\kappa_i(t))^{n-i}=\frac{\det(\dot{c}(t),\ldots,c^{(n)}(t))}{\|\dot{c}(t)\|^{n(n+1)/2}}.$$

**My Idea**: Show it by induction over $n$.

**My solution**: Let $n=2$. Then:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{2-1}\kappa_i(t)^{2-i}= \kappa_1(t) = \frac{\det(\dot{c}(t),\ddot{c}(t))}{\|\dot{c}(t)\|^3}. \checkmark $$

Now, $n-1\mapsto n$:

\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=1}^n (\kappa_i(t))^{n+1-i} &= \prod_{i=1}^n (\kappa_i(t))^{n-i}\cdot\kappa_i(t) \\
&= \kappa_n(t)\cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \kappa_i(t) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\kappa_i(t)^{n-i} \\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \kappa_i(t)\cdot\frac{\det(\dot{c}(t),\ldots,c^{(n)}(t))}{\|\dot{c}(t)\|^{n(n+1)/2}}
\end{align*}

What is $\prod_{i=1}^n \kappa_i(t)$?

Comment: There's not an obvious induction here unless you relate the geometry of a curve in $\Bbb R^n$ to that of its projection into $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to write down the Frenet equations (which actually define the $\kappa_i$) for a curve parametrized by arclength, and then use the product rule to compute the derivatives of $c$. Then use the chain rule to adjust for non-unit-speed curves.